# Performance Discrepancy B/n C++ and Python for Project Euler

Tags: python, c++

I'm experiencing a slightly bizarre performance discrepancy between two equatable programs and I cannot reason about the difference for any real reason.

I'm solving Project Euler Problem 46. Both code solutions (one in Python and one in Cpp) get the right answer. However, the python solution seems to be more performant, which is contradictory to what I was expecting.

Do not worry about the actual algorithm being optimal - all I care about is that they are two equatable programs. I'm sure there is a more optimal algorithm.

#### Python Solution

```
import math
import time

UPPER_LIMIT = 1000000
HIT_COUNT = 0

def sieveOfErato(number):
    sieve = [True] * number
    for i in xrange(2, int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(number)))):
        if sieve[i]:
            for j in xrange(i**2, number, i):
                sieve[j] = False
    primes = [i for i, val in enumerate(sieve) if i > 1 and val == True]
    return set(primes)

def isSquare(number):
    ans = math.sqrt(number).is_integer()
    return ans

def isAppropriateGolbachNumber(number, possiblePrimes):
    global HIT_COUNT
    for possiblePrime in possiblePrimes:
        if possiblePrime < number:
            HIT_COUNT += 1
            difference = number - possiblePrime
            if isSquare(difference / 2):
                return True
    return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    primes = sieveOfErato(UPPER_LIMIT)
    answer = -1
    for odd in xrange(3, UPPER_LIMIT, 2):
        if odd not in primes:
            if not isAppropriateGolbachNumber(odd, primes):
                answer = odd
                break
    print('Hit Count: {}'.format(HIT_COUNT))
    print('Loop Elapsed Time: {}'.format(time.time() - start))
    print('Answer: {}'.format(answer))
```

#### C++ Solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>

int UPPER_LIMIT = 1000000;

std::unordered_set<int> sieveOfErato(int number)
{
    std::unordered_set<int> primes;
    bool sieve[number+1];
    memset(sieve, true, sizeof(sieve));

    for(int i = 2; i * i <= number; i++)
    {
        if (sieve[i] == true)
        {
            for (int j = i*i; j < number; j+=i)
            {
                sieve[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 2; i < number; i++)
    {
        if (sieve[i] == true)
        {
            primes.insert(i);
        }
    }
    return primes;
}

bool isPerfectSquare(const int& number)
{
    int root(round(sqrt(number)));
    return number == root * root;
}

int hitCount = 0;

bool isAppropriateGoldbachNumber(const int& number, const std::unordered_set<int>& primes)
{
    int difference;
    for (const auto& prime : primes)
    {
        if (prime < number)
        {
            hitCount++;
            difference = (number - prime)/2;
            if (isPerfectSquare(difference))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::clock_t start;
    double duration;
    start = std::clock();
    std::unordered_set<int> primes =  sieveOfErato(UPPER_LIMIT);

    int answer = -1;
    for(int odd = 3; odd < UPPER_LIMIT; odd+=2)
    {
        if (primes.find(odd) == primes.end())
        {
            if (!isAppropriateGoldbachNumber(odd, primes))
            {
                answer = odd;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    duration = (std::clock() - start) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    std::cout << "Hit Count: " << hitCount << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::fixed << "Loop Elapsed Time: " << duration << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Answer: " << answer << std::endl;
}
```

I'm compiling my cpp code by `g++ -std=c++14 file.cpp` and then executing with just `./a.out`.

On a couple of test runs just using the `time` command from the command line, I get:

#### Python

```
Hit Count: 128854
Loop Elapsed Time: 0.393740177155
Answer: 5777

real    0m0.525s
user    0m0.416s
sys 0m0.049s
```

#### C++

```
Hit Count: 90622
Loop Elapsed Time: 0.993970
Answer: 5777

real    0m1.027s
user    0m0.999s
sys 0m0.013s
```

Why would there be more hits in the python version and it still be returning more quickly? I would think that more hits, means more iterations, means slower (and it's in python). I'm guessing that there's just a performance blunder in my cpp code, but I haven't found it yet. Any ideas?

Comment: You haven't turned the C++ optimization on. Surely the Python libraries had been optimized.

Comment: Just by the way here, but you don't need to compare an expression that returns a boolean value to another boolean value (e.g. `if (sieve[i] == true)`), as you just get a boolean again.

Comment: @DYZ how do I do that? Why wouldn’t the compiler naturally optimize?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 thanks ya I know I just was being explicit - I know I could have taken that off

Comment: @jlarks32 I see no point using `std::unordered_set` here. Why can't we use `std::vector` by the way?

Comment: Pass an option to your compiler that enables optimization. The actual option depends on the compiler, check the documentation. A compiler does not optimize code by default because optimization is expensive and not necessary during the development stage.

Comment: And why are the hit counts different if they are really implementations of the same algorithm?

Comment: @KunalPuri uh that’s a linear search time versus a constant time search right? I would imagine it would make a difference

Comment: @jlarks32 Which search are you talking about? I think you are iterating over `std::unordered_set`.

Comment: @Selcuk well ok fair enough. I meant implementation of the algos are the same. The hit count is different because the order of the sets is not deterministic so bn the python and cpp version, the total prime count is the same, but they are in dif orders, thus diff sizes, thus diff hit counts. So valid point

Comment: @KunalPuri i'm not sure we're on the same page. 1) yes obviously no prime is even that's why i'm starting from 3 and incrementing by 2 just to find the odd composite numbers. 2) a hashset and a list (or in this case, dynamically allocated array) have fundamentally different underlying datastructures. a hashset (unordered_set) provides O(1) lookup on average. see here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find a vector (list) provides O(n) lookup on average http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/

Comment: @DYZ I turned on the -O2 compiler flag and now the times are relatively equatable for c++. (0.588s, 0.602s, 0.663s, 0.534s, 0.713s), but still on average seem higher. Do you have any other thoughts about why this might be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186693/discussion-between-kunal-puri-and-jlarks32).

Comment: You can try adding -O3 -Ofast -flto -march=native (depending on which of them your compiler supports). My experience shows that `-march=native` makes marvels.

Comment: @DYZ but you literally think the only difference is in compiler optimization? That’s wild

Comment: Optimization or lack of it can easily give or take an order of magnitude, and it's the easiest factor to consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I concur with Kunal Puri's answer that a better algorithm and data-structure can improve performance, but it does not answer the core question: Why does the same algorithm, that uses the same data-structure, runs faster with python.

It all boils down to the difference between `std::unordered_set` and python's `set`. Note that the same C++ code with `std::set` runs faster than python's alternative, and if optimization is enabled (with `-O2`) then C++ code with `std::set` runs more than 10 times faster than python.

There are several works showing that, and why, `std::unordered_set` is broken performance-wise. For example you can watch [C++Now 2018: You Can Do Better than std::unordered_map: New Improvements to Hash Table Performance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M2fKMP47slQ). It seems that python does not suffer from these design flaws in its `set`.

One of the things that make `std::unordered_set` so poor is the big amount of indirections it mandates to simply reach an element. For example, during iteration, the iterator points to a bucket before the current bucket. Another thing to consider is the poorer cache locality. The `set` of python seems to prefer to retain the original order of elements, but the GCC's `std::unordered_set` tends to create a random order. This is the cause of the difference in `HIT_COUNT` between C++ and python. Once the code starts to use `std::set` then the `HIT_COUNT` becomes the same for C++ and python. Retaining the original order during iteration tends to improves the cache locality of nodes in a new process, since they are iterated in the same order as they are allocated (and two adjacent allocations, of a new process, have higher chance to be allocated in consecutive memory addresses).

Comment: This is absolutely perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Apart from compiler optimization as suggested by [DYZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4492932/dyz), I have some more observations regarding optimization.

1) Use `std::vector` instead of `std::unordered_set`.

In your code, you are doing this:

```
std::unordered_set<int> sieveOfErato(int number)
{
    std::unordered_set<int> primes;
    bool sieve[number+1];
    memset(sieve, true, sizeof(sieve));

    for(int i = 2; i * i <= number; i++)
    {
        if (sieve[i] == true)
        {
            for (int j = i*i; j < number; j+=i)
            {
                sieve[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 2; i < number; i++)
    {
        if (sieve[i] == true)
        {
            primes.insert(i);
        }
    }
    return primes;
}
```

I don't see any reason of using `std::unordered_set` here. Instead, you could do this:

```
std::vector<int> sieveOfErato(int number)
{
    bool sieve[number+1];
    memset(sieve, true, sizeof(sieve));

    int numPrimes = 0;

    for(int i = 2; i * i <= number; i++)
    {
        if (sieve[i] == true)
        {
            for (int j = i*i; j < number; j+=i)
            {
                sieve[j] = false;
            }

            numPrimes++;
        }
    }

    std::vector<int> primes(numPrimes);
    int j = 0;

    for(int i = 2; i < number; i++)
    {
        if (sieve[i] == true)
        {
            primes[j++] = i;
        }
    }
    return primes;
}
```

As far as `find()` is concerned, you may do this:

```
int j = 0;
for(int odd = 3; odd < UPPER_LIMIT; odd+=2)
{
    while (j < primes.size() && primes[j] < odd) {
        j++;
    }

    if (primes[j] != odd)
    {
        if (!isAppropriateGoldbachNumber(odd, primes))
        {
            answer = odd;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

2) Pre Compute **perfect squares** in a `std::vector` before hand instead of calling `sqrt` always.

Comment: Right yeah that totally makes sense and is a good catch, but still alludes the original question of what I was asking. Good point tho

Comment: The only other thing about this top solution is that `numPrimes` wouldn't be the right number. But you can just push_back in the vec and it'd be fine.

Comment: @jlarks32 No. If you do push_back, it will take more time as reallocation of memory will be done again and again. And why `numPrimes` is not correct?

Comment: yeah it doesn’t seem to be that bad efficiency wise. And it’s because you’re only iterating up to 1000 (the square root of 1m) but there are definitely primes between 1000 and 1m you know what I mean?

Comment: @jlarks32 But ideally, I think you should not go for `push_back` in such scenarios.